# How can I pass a JavaScript variable generated from an API as part of a form to a php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I have variables generated with a JS Script that I want to pass back to the PHP program that called the script, and trying to figure out the best method for doing that.  Because there are 4-5 variables, I do not want to pass it to php using the url.

The form is using PHP Form Builder and is correctly passing back one variable variable from a Google Maps API JS Script. The PHP code to set up form:

```
$form->addIcon('town-req', '<i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>', 'before');
$form->addInput('text', 'town-req', '', '', 'placeholder=Your town,onFocus=\'geolocate()\', required');
```

The values are stored in a MySQL DB using:

```
= Mysql::SQLValue($_POST['town-req']);
```

Within the script, I can assign the other variables I want to pass back to the PHP, such as latitude and longitude:

```
var lat = place.geometry.location.lat(),
    lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
```

Is it possible to pass these variables such as “lat” to a $_POST as a hidden field in the form?

Or is AJAX is the best way to accomplish this?  Is there an example that can help?

Comment: "Is there an example that can help?"  There are many.  Have you done any searching or made any attempts?

Comment: Both are possible. I would prefer ajax.
Can you provide some code you tried and explain what is not working so we can correct and help you ?

Comment: Ajax is probably your friend here.

Comment: is set up a public repo here - https://github.com/HamletHub/phpform
if you believe it is easier to cut and paste her, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use ajax for this - it was actually much easier than I thought!

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {lng:lng},
    success: function(data) {
    console.log(lng);
    }
})
```